# Image in HTML - spacing between rows in HTML table

Tags: html

I know there have been similar questions, but I'd like some input on my specific code.

I've got an image which I've sliced into 9 pieces, and created a 3x3 HTML table to display it.

But my table get spaces between rows, but no spaces between columns.  I'm not using any CSS.

Any help?

Here's the code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="/storage/Slice-1.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/storage/Slice-2.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/storage/Slice-3.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="/storage/Slice-4.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/storage/Slice-5.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/storage/Slice-6.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="/storage/Slice-7.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/storage/Slice-8.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/storage/Slice-9.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do You need spacing between rows and columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this problem several times when i used to work on emailers in the very beginning of my career.

Try using `align="left" valign="top"` attributes with every `<td>` which contains an image. I guess it will solve your problem with spacing between table rows.

In case it doesn't work out... then i have 1 more solution... but try this out first and see of it works...

Answer (score 2):

1. Use CSS reset http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css
2. Define `display:block` on the images

Answer (score 0):

I know probably really messy, but why not output the images like this:

```
<img src="/storage/Slice-1.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
<img src="/storage/Slice-2.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
<img src="/storage/Slice-3.jpg" border="0" alt="" /><br/>
<img src="/storage/Slice-4.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
<img src="/storage/Slice-5.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
<img src="/storage/Slice-6.jpg" border="0" alt="" /><br/>
<img src="/storage/Slice-7.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
<img src="/storage/Slice-8.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
<img src="/storage/Slice-9.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
```

Call it cheating, but without a CSS reset, table and image padding and margins will be unpredictable to say the least.